# video.js : infinite load on safari after putting the source on CDN

Tags: safari, cross-domain, video.js

The title pretty say it all, a fully fonctional video.js player broke on safari for mac after moving the video on a distant media server. It works on chrome, firefox and IEs.

my first guess is a cross server issue, but it shoudln't work on others browsers if it was the case.

Comment: fixed my issue by forcing flash player in desktop safari. I'm still interested in a solution, since videos still doesn't play on ipad, where i can't force flash player obviously.

Comment: on apple mobile devices you can not use flash, that's why you should have the mp4 versions of your files also. So the video.js can fall back to mp4 if there is no flash on the client side.

Comment: The html5 version is broken on safari with cdn, it's the original bug, so it's always broken on apple mobile device.